# Fullcalendar eventDragStop returns previous date

Tags: fullcalendar, angular8

I am working on Angular full calendar and trying to update the reservation when user drags the event to an other time. But when I log the event it returns me the previous start and end time. How can I get the current start and end time?

```
    <full-calendar
        defaultView="dayGridMonth"
        [editable]="true"
        [eventLimit]="5"
        [slotDuration]="'00:15:00'"
        [snapDuration]="'00:15:00'"
        [nowIndicator]="true"
        [slotLabelFormat]="timeFormat"
        [eventTimeFormat]="timeFormat"
        [minTime]="'08:00:00'"
        [maxTime]="'24:00:00'"
        [header]="{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek, timeGridDay, listWeek'
        }"
        [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
        [events]="calendarEvents"
        (eventDragStop)="updateReservation($event)"

    ></full-calendar>
```

And this it the updateReservation method:

```
updateReservation(event) {
    console.log(event, event.el.fcSeg.start, moment(event.el.fcSeg.start).format());
}
```

Hope someone could help me out :)

Comment: Use eventDrop instead. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop .

Comment: @ADyson thats working indeed! Thanks, do you maybe know how I can pass the reservation id to the event? This is not working:
const event = { id: value._id}

Comment: Where does your reservation ID come from in the first place? It would help if you showed your code in context, as well

Comment: From backend api, but I pass it to the event object but I only see the start and end time etc. I will show full code in a bit.

Comment: did you forget to show the code...or did you solve it already?

Comment: @ADyson oh excuse me yes I solved it, thanks for checking in again :)

Comment: Great. In that case please add your solution below, in the Answers section so that others with similar issues might benefit from it, and also you can be upvoted if people find it useful. Or...if the solution was some trivial error like a typo that we would not learn from then please just delete the question. But either way, don't just leave an unanswered question lying around when the answer is already known to you - thanks :-)